# Верстка резинового центрального блока с использованием flexbox

Tags: css, вёрстка

1. Есть родительский блок высотой 500px
2. Есть контейнер который тянется на всю высоту родительского блока
3. Он имеет 2 дочерних дива

Как сделать так чтобы див под номером 1 когда в нем очень много контента не выталкивал блок под номером 2, а тянулся только на сколько есть места чтобы блок 2 прилип к низу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: указать максимальную высоту

Comment: такой вариант не пойдет так-как под номером 2 пагинация и она не должна висеть внизу с пустым блоком сверху (имеющим максимальную высоту)

Comment: дак она и не будет висеть снизу, у вас блок 1 будет динамическим, его высота будет основываться на контенте, который находится в нём, но если контент будет превышать, допустим, `400px`, то появится скролл

Comment: а если родительский элемент это body или блок растянутый на всю высоту своего родителя

Comment: у вас ведь указана статическая высота в `500px`?

Comment: просто нужно универсальное решение статическая высота это как пример